# Using NGINX, css files not working

Tags: html, css, nginx

The css files are loading but the issue is that they're not applying, but here's the strange part. If I edit it in chrome in any way (typing a character and deleting it), the style sheet applies. I'm fairly certain the issue is with nginx because when I run a local server (node.js http-server), the css file works.

I added this to my config to make sure it was sending and being interpreted as the right type of file but it still doesn't work.

```
location ~ \.css {
  add_header Content-Type text/css;
}
```

[This is the website if anyone wants to look at it or try editing the css file.](http://tacticalpha.xyz/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a look at the headers sent to the browser, one receives two content-types now which is wrong. The browser interpretes the CSS as plain/text and hence cannot apply the css.

```
Content-Type:text/plain
Content-Type:text/css
```

What does your nginx config look like? Do you include /etc/nginx/mime.types; anywhere alike here: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/

Comment: Thanks, I was being dumb and didn't include that. This is my first time using nginx. Everything works now!